# Python 3.x: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I alraedy checked existing questions. None of them works for me.

I wrote some code to scrape information from multiple pages in a website.

When I run the code, it returns this error:
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)

When I test the code on a limited number of links it works.
The problem is probably this link:

```
'https://www.crowdcube.com/investment/brüpond-brewery-10622'
```

Because there is the ü

In this specific case, I can drop that link and it is ok. However I would like to know how to handle this problem in general.

Here there is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib 
from time import sleep 
import re



def make_soup(url):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

def get_links(section_url):
    get_link = make_soup(section_url)
    links_page = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in get_link.select('a[href]')]
    links_page = list(set(links_page))


    links = [l for l in links_page if 'https://www.crowdcube.com/investment/' in l] 

    return links

def get_data(url):
miss='.'
tree= make_soup(url)
try:
    #title
    title = tree.find_all('h2')[0].get_text()

    #description
    description=tree.find_all('div',{'class':'fullwidth'})
    description= description[1].find('p').get_text()
    description=re.sub(r'[^\w.]', ' ', description)   

   #location
    location=tree.find_all('div',{'class':'pitch-profile'})
    location=location[0].find('li').get_text()
    l=0
    loc=list(location)
    while l < len(loc):
       if loc[l]==',':
           loc[l]='-'
       l+=1   
    del(loc[0:10])
    location="".join(loc)
   #raised capital
    raised=tree.find_all('div',{'class':'cc-pitch__raised'})
    raised= raised[0].find('b').get_text()

    rais=list(raised)

    r=0
    while r < len(rais):
        if rais[r]==',':
           rais[r]='.'
        r+=1   

    currency=rais[0]

    del(rais[0])

    raised="".join(rais)

    #target
    target=tree.find_all('div',{'class':'cc-pitch__stats clearfix'})
    target= target[0].find('dd').get_text()
    targ=list(target)

    t=0
    while t < len(targ):
        if targ[t]==',':
           targ[t]='.'
        t+=1   


    del(targ[0])

    target="".join(targ)

    #category

    category=tree.find_all('li',{'class':'sectors'})
    category=category[0].find('span').get_text()

    category=category.strip()
    category=category.replace(" ", "")
    cat=list(category)    
    c=0
    while c < len(cat):
        if cat[c]==',':
           cat[c]='-'
        c+=1   
    category="".join(cat)

    backers=tree.find_all('div',{'class':'cc-pitch__stats clearfix'})

    for tag in backers:
        ddTags = tag.find_all("dd")


    backers= ddTags[3].get_text()


    backers

    return {"url": url.encode("utf-8"),
            "title": title.encode("utf-8"),
            "backers":backers.encode("utf-8"),
            "description":description.encode("utf-8"),
            "location":location.encode("utf-8"),
            "raised": raised.encode("utf-8"),
            "currency":currency.encode("utf-8"),
            "target": target.encode("utf-8"),
            "category": category.encode("utf-8")}
except(IndexError,RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, UnicodeEncodeError):
    return {"url": url,
            "title": miss,
            "backers":miss,
            "description":miss,
            "location":miss,
            "raised": miss,
            "currency":miss,
            "target": miss,
            "category": miss}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_url = ("https://www.crowdcube.com/investments?sort_by=0&q=&hof=1&i1=0&i2=0&i3=0&i4=0&sort_by=7")

links = get_links(start_url)

data = [] # a list to store our dictionaries
for link in links:
    crowdcube = get_data(link)
    data.append(crowdcube)
    sleep(1)
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you have two issues but haven't included the relevant code - probably in the `make_soup` function. Please restrict the question to one problem and include complete and verifiable code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack i fixed my question. Hope now it is ok

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack line 973, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))

Comment: That line isn't in your code! Please include the whole stack trace. Also, please indent your code properly.

Comment: You're trapping many of the common exceptions so you won't know what the errors are. Remove the `except` statement and re-run.

Comment: Also, why are you encoding the results? Most of those variables should be str's already

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I did it because I tought the problem was somewhere there. But I will definetively remove the encoding there. 
The except is because a couple of (very old) pages  had a different html structure. The problem existed even before I used the except at same line

Comment: Your exception catching is too broad. You should only catch exceptions you  expect - this is a case in point

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I understand your point. Now I will fix it. Apologize me, Just started writing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urllib can't handle umlauts like the 'ü' in in the Url:

```
'https://www.crowdcube.com/investment/brüpond-brewery-10622'
```

Use the [requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). The requests lib has no Problems with umlauts.

For example change your make_soup function to this:

```
import requests

def make_soup(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```